# How do I declare a class that implements an interface that constrains the type of a class?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've seen examples of how to declare a generic class whose type parameter is constrained, e.g. it must extend Comparable. I also know how to define an interface for a generic class whose type is similarly constrained. However, when I do the latter, I'm unable to figure out the syntax for the class signature. So, to cut a long story short, if the interface is

```
public interface iMyClass<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

what should be the syntax for the signature for the implementing class

```
public class MyClass.......
```

Thanks in advance,
D

Comment: `public class MyClass implements iMyClass<Any class that extends Comparable>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you intend `MyClass` to be generic as well? If so,

```
public class MyClass<? extends Comparable<T>> implements iMyClass<T> {
```

Otherwise, keep things simple and

```
public class MyClass implements iMyClass<String> {
```

Replace `String` with your `Comparable`.

Comment: Yes the class has to be generic too. But arrrggg, that is what I was writing too and it wasn't working....but after staring at the error message "class or interface expected" some more , I realized that that first "implements" should be "extends". Now it works.  Thanks

Comment: Note - please edit your original answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: In that case, you might want to see if you really want to expose MyClass at all. Simpler alternative would be to use an object factory.
BTW, I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

A constrained type argument is supplied in exactly the same way as a non-constrained one, for instance:

```
public class MyClass implements iMyClass<String> {
```